# Various ppa's still appear in the list after removing them from the Software GUI

Tags: apt, software-center, uninstall, ppa

I keep having this issue over and over and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I want to discard/remove ppa depositories from my system and I've tried a few solutions offered by users here as well but I still see them when I perform the command:

```
sudo ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

However, I had previously deleted them from the Software Center, I cannot find the packages either so I don't know if they're still in the system or how can I remove them. Is there any way I can get rid of them? They're a lot and all the apps and programs that were installed with them are gone actually. Also, I'm trying to delete sets of icons and I can't do it either.

Thank you for your time!

**EDIT:** Solved my problem! I managed to delete the .list files. Deleting them directly from the directory */etc/apt/sources.list.d* could not be done but through the terminal using this command instead:

```
sudo rm -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/PPA_NAME.list
```

This is how I could delete them. Thanks again!

Comment: You can delete the `.list` files corresponding to the PPA you removed. As far as I know, the GUI only deletes the file content, but leaves an empty (and therefore ignored) file behind.

Comment: Thank you! After searching for the .list files I could delete them. I wasn't able to delete them from the directory itself but managed to get it done through terminal.

Comment: Deleting files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d is the **wrong** way to solve your problem. You shouldn't be poking around in parts of the system that you don't know what they do. The **correct** way to remove PPA repositories is from `Software & Updates` "other software" tab. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 1):

Deleting files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d is the **wrong** way to solve your problem. You shouldn't be poking around in parts of the system that you don't know what they do. The **correct** way to remove PPA repositories is from `Software & Updates` "other software" tab. Cheers, Al